# How do you convert normal time to a time that can be saved Django TimeField?

Tags: python, django

I have program that enables users choose day(s) in which they would want to be sent notifications.

`days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']`

`time_otd = ['1am', '2am', '3am', '4am', '5am', '6am', '7am']`

Assuming a user selects **mon** and **6am**, how do you convert it to Django [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#timefield) so that the program sends notification to the user every Monday by **6am**?

**P.s**:

Both day and time have different columns in my model. So, the main to solve here is the conversion of user-selected time.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Django time". And a TimeField stores times, as the name implies, not times and days.

Comment: Okay. I will edit the title appropriately. But do you understand what I want to do?

Comment: Just store 6am as time, and store Monday separately however you want (as 0 or 'mon'). You won't be able to store both inside any of the standard fields easily (unless you store them as a concatenated string or something).